# Unity - Distribution build crash - EXC_BAD_ACCESS - KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crash, app-store-connect, unity3d-cloud-build

I have developed a game on Unity (2019.2.16f1) and I have a **big problem** :
The build submitted to the App Store crash after 1 second (on startup)

Some more informations :

- I coded some c# script, but most of the game is running with Bolt (Ludiq / Visual scripting)
- I use the Unity Cloud Building service (For development and distribution build)
- The development build dont crash. Only the distribution build. (The one submitted to the app store connect)
- I distribute the ipa file with the mac "Transporter" application
- I use UnityAds in this game

Here is the main log :

---

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000003a
VM Region Info: 0x3a is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4367777734
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 0000000104570000-0000000104574000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ....app/z4league
```

---

(Full Log : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wjLG5oKqP_isgPce8ND5Nrz7wYtoiC2OIXc1cN9sPy0/edit?usp=sharing)

Did someone had this (quite obscur) problem ?
I did some research on google, but nothing seems to be appropriate to my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find the **exact** solution of this problem.

What I did is remove "Bolt" from the project and re-code everything in c#.
(By the way, incredible exercise for learning to code c# in Unity)

My game is now validated by Apple and ready to go live

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the location of your project files. It is trying to access that location. It could also be a problem which is caused by app store. "The development build doesn't crash. Only the distribution build." <- This is caused by you. You did something wrong when building the app or releasing it for distribution. Try to give access to the location where you have your project files. And also try watching a tutorial for releasing your app for distribution from YouTubers like Brackeys etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Two questions : 1 - How can I give access to that location ? Specificaly ?
2 - How can the difference between development et distribution build can be caused by me since i use the cloud building for both ? There is absolutly no diffrence in my building flow between the two of them ...

Thanks for your reply anyway ! :)